# Determining size of controls for portable desktop application

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, user-interface, resolution

I am new to professional development of UI application. I wonder what the normal approach to decide the layout of the each UI element. 
Do people hard-code the size elements according to the design time monitor size? And later scale the UI size dynamically?
Or do people use some dynamical approach to set each UI element proportional according to screen size? I meant if there's a method dynamically to set controls size proportional to screen size and that ratio is hard-coded by programmer. Obviously, Dockpanel or viewbox are automatic adjusting. Or do people usually decided size upon design time?
Or there're other common approach?

Answer (score 1):

Its generally recommended to have size of the elements proportional according to screen size. WPF has lot many features to achieve these functions. Since you where new to WPF, have brief knowledge about the [WPF Panels](http://www.wpf-training-guide.com/wpf-panels.html). Also if you would like to stick with the existing layout and you need to expand the layout proportionally make use of `ViewBox` in WPF.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple answer to this. The WPF composition does a lot of hard work for you, if you let it.

If I can help it, I do not specify Width's and Height's but I would be lying if I said that I never do. In some data entry applications, there is no choice but where I do have a choice, I will let the WPF composition system do the work for me. Margins are the only layout property that will always get a look-in.

**The WPF Composition system**

The WPF Composition system will pass over your logical tree twice, once to measure the elements and once to arrange the elements based on the collected information. Some elements, such as panels, will attempt to take up as much space as they can. Some elements will attempt to constrict their contents as much as possible. Some elements will take up only the space they need.

An example is if you put a TextBox in a Grid without specifying Width's and Height's, the TextBox will take up the entire 'content' area of the Grid. If you do the same with a TextBox and a StackPanel, the StackPanel will constrain the TextBox to the MinHeight of the TextBox. Put a CheckBox in the Grid and it will take up only the area it needs.

**Conclusion**

There is no simple way to learn this other than to play.

I recommend reading the following links

[WPF Architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750441%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[Trees in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753391%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

They are both long reads but worth while. They will give you the theory you need to search for more practical applications of WPF and there are a lot of good blog entries out there that cover this topic.